# How to distinct result in SQL VIEW select query with JOIN?

Tags: sql, select, join

I have a view with select query with join.

```
SELECT
 t.a, 
 t.b,
 (SELECT CASE WHEN t2.field IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS Expr1) AS C
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2 on t2.link = t1.link
```

If in table2 there is more than 1 entry with same link, i'm getting duplicated entries.

What is the correct way to distinct result? Is there a type of JOIN, that won't return all result, but only single row?

Thank you

Comment: As a note, when you post a question, make sure your code examples are accurate. This example would not run on any DBMS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they are really duplicates, if you use distinct they are removed:

```
SELECT
 distinct
 t.a, 
 t.b,
 (SELECT CASE WHEN t2.field IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS Expr1) AS C
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2 on t2.link = t1.link
```

Comment: @Sergejs when we don't know, we don't know :P

Answer (score 6):

```
select distinct t.a, t.b ...
```

should eliminate duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
    t.a, 
    t.b,
    CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT * FROM table2 t2 WHERE t2.link = t1.link) 
           THEN 1 
           ELSE 0
    END AS c
FROM table1 t1
```